# How to Change some dictionary field position after I sort them by value alphabetically

Tags: c#, dictionary, enums

I have one Enum AllTypes

```
public enum AllTypes
    {
        [Description("Best")]
         best = 0,
        [Description("Adv")]
         adv = 1,
        [Description("Cas")]
         cas = 21,
        [Description("Cas2")]
        cas2 = 3,
        [Description("Cat")]
        cat = 4,
        [Description("E-test")]
        e-test = 5,
        [Description("Edit")]
        edit = 6,
        [Description("Ev")]
        ev = 7,
        [Description("Git")]
        git = 8,
        [Description("Ga")]
        ga = 9,
        [Description("Zb")]
        zb = 10
        [Description("Test")]
        test = 20
    }
```

For Extract this Enum in alphabetical order I call this method:

```
public static IDictionary<int, string> GetAllTypes<TEnum>() where TEnum : struct
    {
        var enumerationType = typeof(TEnum);

        if (!enumerationType.IsEnum)
            throw new ArgumentException("Enumeration type is expected.");

        var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        foreach (int value in Enum.GetValues(enumerationType))
        {
            var name = GetDescription((MyEnums.AllTypes)value);
            dictionary.Add(value, name);
        }

        var sorted = from dictionar in dictionary
                     orderby dictionar.Value ascending
                     select dictionar;
        var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        foreach (var item in sorted)
        {
            dict.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
        }
        return dict;
    }
```

Now I want to change position of Best Type to Put it in the first position to dictionary, I i remove it by key and then add in dictionary it is placed in third position, some proposal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by others, you have to use the `SortedDictionary` class.

However, you need to do more.

1) You want a special value of the Enum to be the first.

2) You want to sort by the description. `SortedDictionary` sorts by the key not the value.

I suggest to do the following:

Define a special comparer class that allows us to specify a special function for comparing like this:

```
public class CustomComparer<T> : IComparer<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T, T, int> m_Comparer;

    public CustomComparer(Func<T, T, int> comparer)
    {
        m_Comparer = comparer;
    }

    public int Compare(T x, T y)
    {
        return m_Comparer(x, y);
    }
}
```

Then use the `SortedDictionary` with this comparer:

```
public static IDictionary<int, string> GetAllTypes<TEnum>(TEnum special_value) where TEnum : struct
{
    var enumerationType = typeof(TEnum);

    if (!enumerationType.IsEnum)
        throw new ArgumentException("Enumeration type is expected.");

    int special_value_int = Convert.ToInt32(special_value);

    var dictionary = new SortedDictionary<int, string>(
        new CustomComparer<int>((x, y) =>
        {
            if (x == special_value_int && x != y)
                return -1;

            if (y == special_value_int && x != y)
                return 1;

            var description_x = GetDescription((AllTypes) x);
            var description_y = GetDescription((AllTypes)y);

            return description_x.CompareTo(description_y);
        }));

    foreach (int value in Enum.GetValues(enumerationType))
    {
        var name = GetDescription((AllTypes)value);
        dictionary.Add(value, name);
    }
    return dictionary;
}
```

Please note how I am defining a special function that treats the special value as the smaller one, and that uses the description of the enum for the comparison.

Here is how you can use it:

```
var result = GetAllTypes<AllTypes>(AllTypes.best);
```

Here I am specifying the special value that should be in the start.

Comment: after I test your code, I have the same results, only in alphabetically order, AllTypes.best is on the third position (

Comment: @Alex, I tried it here and I have no issue. I just modified the answer. I am not sure if the modification will fix it.

Comment: Yep, after you edit, the result is that what I want, thank you very much for your time and for help

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries aren't ordered, so you'd be better of using something like `List<KeyValuePair>` or `SortedDictionary`